# Disable ivy for find-file

Tags: dired, find-file, ivy

Is it possible to disable `ivy-mode` for file prompts?

In a past I used `find-file` to copy current file name or path to file.

`dired-do-rename` also is broken by Ivy: no default completion for current file + editing key binding extremely altered / navigation disabled...

Comment: That sounds like two questions, and the second sounds a bit like a bug report for Ivy. Also: what do you mean by using `find-file` to copy the current file name, and how does Ivy prevent doing that?

Comment: `find-file` is useful for copying file name of current buffer. On UP key default completion brings current buffer file name. Then you can select it.

Comment: OK, please consider adding that description to the question, to make this clear.

Answer (score 2):

`Ivy-mode` changes the value of `completing-read-function`. This function is used internally by `read-file-name-default` which is used for file name completion. The function used for file name completion can be changed using the variable `read-file-name-function`. By dynamically binding `completing-read-function` back to the default before calling `read-file-name-default` you will get what you want:

```
(setq read-file-name-function
  (lambda (&rest args)
    (let ((completing-read-function #'completing-read-default))
      (apply #'read-file-name-default args))))
```

Note that if you use `counsel-mode`, you have to undo the rebinding it does for `find-file`:

```
(define-key counsel-mode-map [remap find-file] nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ivy supports multiple actions for the selected candidate. You can add your own actions, but by default there is a copy action that may be exactly what you need.

With the default key bindings, you can use `M-o` in the minibuffer to bring up the ivy action menu, and `w` to copy the currently selected candidate.

EDIT

I see this does not quite address your use case, since the current file name is not the default candidate for `find-file` when ivy is enabled. I always used to use `find-alternate-file` (`C-x C-v`) as a quick way to grab the current file name, and this works fine with ivy using `M-o w` as noted above. (Now I just have a separate key binding to copy `buffer-file-name` directly.)